# Does Islam mention a caste system within marriage?

Tags: nikah, caste

This question is motivated by a personal problem:  I am in my late 20s wanting to get married to a good guy I know. We both are Bengali, Muslim; he has a good job, is on the deen, both educated to a high level. My parents first were okay with it as he was Bengali/Muslim, but once looked into it properly, they are refusing because he is apparently of a lower caste than me! (Something about fishmongers). I've tried to explain this is unislamic (more Hindu ways if anything), and I am trying to do the right thing and make my relationship Halal for us and in the eyes of Allah, but I am being told caste is Islamic? I am stuck and no longer know what to do. I am being told marrying into this caste is an unimaginable thing to do, almost degrading but I really don't see how. He and his family are good people so I'm confused about this caste issue.

I would like to know: Does Islam mention a caste system within marriage and how best to approach this?

Please don't judge about the relationship, rather assist me on this matter please.

Comment: All muslim are equal . Please read Prophet Muhammad's Last Sermon http://www.introductiontoislam.org/prophetlastsermon.shtml

Comment: I'm Bengali/Muslim and the reason why your parents say he is 'lower caste' is because of the native Hindus. Muslim conquerors of India adopted the caste system and Bangladesh was part of India during that time. It is against Islam as everyone is equal.

Comment: @armaan can you please reference about "adopted the caste system" claim?

Comment: Caste, color, looks is totally irrelevant in Islam. It is the deen that is the most important thing. NOWHERE does it say in the Quran that a person must be of a certain caste or color or height or certain color of eyes etc... except that you must choose the person who has strong deen as that is the most important thing and must be looked at!

Comment: @kmonsoor 'According to M. N. Srinivas (1986), Indian Hindu converts to Islam brought their original caste system to the Muslim society in the region. On the other hand, Louis Dumont (1957) believes that the Islamic conquerors consciously adopted the Hindu caste system.'

Comment: There's no caste system within Islam, perhaps you're thinking of class?

Answer (score 0):

As muslims we must respect our parents, where are the limits to the obedience to our parents related to choose our spouse? I´ve seen how people get bitter seeing how their lives pass by without giving one step forward, specially women, we care about time because we cannot wait forever, and man are not able to move because they don´t have the way to do it without the approval of their parents, many times they depend financially from their families and don´t have option to move from their family homes, ... don´t know how to begin or how to end.

I would encourage you to talk to your parents in a quiet, simple, loving and respectful way how you feel and bring forward our muslim roots, this caste issue has nothing to do with Islam.

Read this for more [**1**](http://www.zawaj.com/askbilqis/parents-preventing-marriage-due-caste/) **[2](http://www.zawaj.com/askbilqis/parents-not-agreeing-choice-of-wife/)**